# I have a TCP IP client server with ontly one cilent allowed to connect to sever. Do I need semaphores?

Tags: java, sockets, semaphore

I have a Java TCPIP cient/server where there is only one client allowed.
I am contemplated if I should need to add any semaphore protection.

I'm thinking no but I have a loop where I wait for socket connection,once I'm connected I will read from the socket. At the same time at any time I can also write out to the socket.

#### Server Implementation

```
Server{
  run(){
     while(true){
        openSocketConnection();  // wait unit client connected
        readSocecketMsg();
     }
  } 

  private void writeMsgToClient(message){
     write to socket(message)
  }
}
```

Comment: Protect against what?

Comment: I would say, You try it with & without semaphore protection.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Youre right!

Comment: @Hydroid not quite. Concurrency bugs very rarely show up unless you explicitly reproduce the exact condition triggering them

Comment: I could be trying to read and write at the same time.

Comment: Why should only one client connect? If your server accepts only one connection, you don't have to fear that anyone else connects. I guess I don't get your question/problem...

Answer (score 0):

You've already done it. You are handling one client at a time. You can't prevent other clients from connecting while you're processing the current one, because of the TCP backlog queue, but you can provide zero service to the next one until you're done with this one, and that's exactly what you're already doing. No semaphore required.